# How do you change which language the built in Spell Checker uses in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: visual-studio-2022, spell-checking

I've recently updated my Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 to version Version 17.5.2 and now get loads of spelling errors.

Is there a way to change the spell checker to use British English?

The flood of warnings for "Spelling error - Colour is not a word" is not helpful at all.

My windows language and region settings are set to English (United Kingdom).

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Spell-checking-does-not-respect-the-user/10364247?q=spell+check+language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the spell checker through an .editorconfig file, as stated in the blog post about the spell checker [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-spell-checker-preview-now-available/#customizing-the-spell-checker):

```
spelling_languages = _language_[,_language_]
(Example: = en-us,fr-fr)
```

I believe in your case, you want it to be:

```
spelling_languages = en-gb
```

The documentation also states the proper language pack must be installed, or it won't work (sounds like you already have that taken care of):

> Note that the fr-fr language pack must be installed on the user’s machine or Visual Studio will incorrectly flag any French words as spelling errors.

Comment: I have tried that but it had no effect. Still complains about colour. I can only see a single language pack for English, there are not different English versions.

Comment: @Smartie an alternative may be to use the `spelling_exclusion_path` which allows you to specify a .dic file of words that should be ignored. This might not be ideal if you have a lot of words to add, but I can only think of a handful of words that are spelt different between US and GB English.

Comment: For anyone try it should be "spelling_languages" not "spelling_lanaguages"

Comment: I don't know how to change the language, but you can at least switch it off (and on) in visual studio (tested on  Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) 
Version 17.5.4)  under edit/advanced/toggle text spell checker.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response but "spelling_languages = en-gb" worked with the correct spelling ^^

Answer (score 5):

Windows [needs to have the correct language pack](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/improving-the-spell-checker/#comment-28476) installed.

Use powershell to get things set up and restart visual studio.

```
PS C:\> Install-Language en-gb
```

I found out that the .editorconfig parser is quite picky, try to start with a minimal version like that:

```
[*]
spelling_languages = en-US,en-GB
spelling_exclusion_path = .\exclusion.dic
```

Comment: Windows is set to UK English, Visual Studio is still complaining about my English spelling of colour.

Comment: Just to be certain. Powershell command `PS C:\> Get-InstalledLanguage` does list something like (containing en-US):

`Language Language Packs  Language Features`
`-------- --------------  -----------------`
`de-AT    None            TextToSpeech`
`de-DE    LpCab, LXP      BasicTyping, Handwriting, Speech, TextToSpeech, OCR`
`en-US    LpCab           BasicTyping, Handwriting, Speech, TextToSpeech, OCR`

In my case adding "en-US" was sufficent to get "Colour" and "Color" passing spell checking.

Comment: Works great on my laptop, but what do I do on the terminal server, where these cmdlets are not supported? Their documentation explicitly states `These cmdlets are supported on client operating system only.` (taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/languagepackmanagement/?view=windowsserver2022-ps)